# mysql-server: Setting bind-address not working without launching manually as root

Tags: networking, mysql, pi-1, raspbian-buster

I haven't been able to get my mysql-server on my raspberry pi to communicate with other network devices with networking enabled unless I manually start the server myself with `sudo mysqld --bind-address 0.0.0.0` (I tried using a local address as well, still no luck).

When I check `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep mysqld` to see if it's listening on the network, it isn't unless I run as root with --bind-address set.

Here is my config, if it helps determine the problem:

````
conf.d  debian.cnf  debian-start  mariadb.cnf  mariadb.conf.d  my.cnf  my.cnf.fallback
pi@pi1:~ $ cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf
# The MariaDB configuration file
[client-server]

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
language        = /usr/share/mysql/English
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
# skip-networking

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
pi@pi1:~ $```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a directory at
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d ?
If so, look for a file named '50-server.cnf'. Try changing the bind-address to 0.0.0.0 in that file and reboot.
The default on my install doesn't have a /etc/my.conf and reads the config from the file above.

Comment: That was the issue, thanks! I've never seen any mention of this config file before...